# how to know our billing information in aws using PHP API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

can we know amazon web services account billing information through php API ?
If yes please provide the solution...

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I searched about that question, but i can't find the solution so i came to stack overflow .

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/api-reference.html

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/

Comment: can we use php API for know our bill report? I want to know the bill report in my root account with details of sub accounts

Answer (score 1):

You can know the billing information using the [PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html)

If you're using a consolidated billing account you'll only need to use the credentials for this account. it will aggregate all the billing information to the consolidated billing account.

In general you need to cover several items:

1. Authentication - You'll need to set up your credentials to be able to connect to AWS. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)
2. Enable DBR or CUR reports in the billing console. This will export your monthly billing information to S3. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-gettingstarted-turnonreports.html)
3. Once ready use the SDK to download the reports and import them to DB, ES, whatever you're working with to process large excel files. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html)

Good luck!

**EDIT**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/namespace-Aws.CostExplorer.html

AWS released Cost Explorer API to get billing information. You can use the documentation to set it up, it's quite straightforward and simple.

Comment: i have three aws account under one root account ,
 now i am doing to get billing information by this way
 " login to root account -> getting billing information by different account ->save  logs into database "
 for everyday billing amount for tracking purpose
 i need a php API to get total billing for up to date from root account for all individual account,
if its possible i wrote a php program and set a cron job for this 
in this way i can log a bill automatically. need is  php function to get total bill amount of various account from root aws account  can anyone help?

Comment: You don't have API access to the billing console. You need to export your billing information to S3 using the DBR (almost deprecated) or the CUR. It is a CSV file containing all the billing information you need, including under which account the billing was made.

Comment: Cost Explorer API is not free of cost. see https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/

Comment: I never said it's free. BUT - I use it extensively and I got like a $2 charge. For visibility it is more than worth it