# How can i get Bill Details By Account Using AWS SDK for PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to get the Billing Details By Account Using PHP AWS SDK.
I am not sure which api to use for that purpose.

Is it even possible to get that?

Comment: Don't show sensitive information to any public platform. You never know when someone can harm you....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134523/how-to-know-our-billing-information-in-aws-using-php-api